# LeadTools MaximumGlobalRasterImageMemory

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, leadtools-sdk

In my web application i use LeadTools to Create Multi Page Tiff file from stream. Below is a code that shows how I use leadtools.

```
using (RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs())
{
    RasterImage ImageToAppened = default(RasterImage);
    RasterImage imageSrc = default(RasterImage);
    codecs.Options.Load.AllPages = true;
    ImageToAppened = codecs.Load(fullInputPath, 1);
    FileInfo fileInfooutputTiff = new FileInfo(fullOutputPath);
    if (fileInfooutputTiff.Exists)
    {
        imageSrc = codecs.Load(fullOutputPath);
        imageSrc.AddPage(ImageToAppened);
        codecs.Save(imageSrc, fullOutputPath, RasterImageFormat.Ccitt, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        codecs.Save(ImageToAppened, fullOutputPath, RasterImageFormat.Ccitt, 1);
    }
}
```

Above code works properly and i get many request for my web application at around 2000 requests. In some cases i get below error . But later on again it works properly for other request.

```
You have exceeded the amount of memory allowed for RasterImage allocations.See RasterDefaults::MemoryThreshold::MaximumGlobalRasterImageMemory.
```

Is that memory issue is for single request or for all the objects during the application started(global object)?
So what is the solution for above error?

Comment: Did you try to read [documentation](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19m/dh/l/rastermemorythreshold-maximumglobalrasterimagememory.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling files with many pages, here are a few general tips that could help with both web and desktop applications:

- Avoid loading all pages and adding them to one RasterImage in memory. Instead loop through them and load them one (or a few) at a time, then append them to output file without keeping them in memory. Appending to file could get slower as the page count grows, but [this help topic](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19m/dh/to/l-topics-loadingandsavinglargetifffiles.html) explains how you can speed that up.
- You have "using (RasterCodecs codecs ..)" in your code, but the large memory is for the image, not the codecs object. Consider wrapping your RasterImage object in a "using" scope to speed up its disposal. In other words, go for "using (RasterImage image = ...)"
- And the obvious suggestion: go for 64-bit, install as much RAM as you can and increase the value of MaximumGlobalRasterImageMemory.

Answer (score 3):

The error you report references the **MaximumGlobalRasterImageMemory**:

> You have exceeded the amount of memory allowed for RasterImage allocations.See RasterDefaults::MemoryThreshold::MaximumGlobalRasterImageMemory.

In the [documentation](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19m/dh/l/rastermemorythreshold-maximumglobalrasterimagememory.html) it states:

> Gets or sets a value that specifies the maximum size allowed for all RasterImage object allocations.
>
> When allocating a new RasterImage object, if the new allocation causes the total memory used by all allocated RasterImage objects to exceed the value of MaximumGlobalRasterImageMemory, then the allocation will throw an exception.

So it looks like it's for all objects.

These are the specified default values:

> On x86 systems, this property defaults to 1.5 GB.
>
> On x64 systems, this property defaults to either 1.5 GB or 75 percent of the system's total physical RAM, whichever is larger.

I would advise that you familiarise yourself with the documentation for the SDK.

Comment: Yes. I have seen this article. But is this limitation is for application level or a single request(If i have large tiff file)?

Comment: Read the documentation and my answer again - it clearly says the total memory used by ALL allocated RasterImage objects.

Comment: ok. I am guessing that RasterImage objects are not disposed properly. So will calling dispose methods after using objects may help. Because garbage collector may not process them automatically faster. Will calling dispose methods after using rasterimages help? Any idea.

Comment: I've explained the source of your error - it's up to you to code a solution. I would think the objects are disposed properly, but perhaps you have multiple RasterImages allocated simultaneously, since this is a **global** limit.

Comment: @Navaneeth did this answer help in any way?